# Dropdown default selection in Angular

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have following dropdown implementation in Angular. But I want to display the `Paris` as a default , but it shows `None` even though I assign value as `1` as follows.

**.html**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="labels" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name" (onChange)="cityChanged($event.value)"></p-dropdown>
```

**.ts**

```
interface City{
    name: string;
    value: number;
}
export class CityComponent {

 selectedCity: number = 1;

  constructor() {
    this.labels = [
        {name: 'None', value: 0},
        {name: 'Paris', value: 1},
        {name: 'Rome', value: 2},
        {name: 'London', value: 3},
        {name: 'Istanbul', value: 4},
        {name: 'Amsterdam', value: 5},
        {name: 'Moscow', value: 6},
        {name: 'Zurich', value: 7}
     ];
  }

  cityChanged(city : City)
  {
      this.selectedCity = city.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the dropdown expects the selected value to match one of your options. Since you are storing your options as objects, but your value as a number, it is unable to find a match. The simplest approach to fix this would be to store the whole object as the `selectedCity`, grabbing just the value once it is needed:

```
export class CityComponent {

 selectedCity = {name: 'Paris', value: 1};

  constructor() {
    this.labels = [
        {name: 'None', value: 0},
        {name: 'Paris', value: 1},
        {name: 'Rome', value: 2},
        {name: 'London', value: 3},
        {name: 'Istanbul', value: 4},
        {name: 'Amsterdam', value: 5},
        {name: 'Moscow', value: 6},
        {name: 'Zurich', value: 7}
     ];
  }

  getSelectedValue(): number {
      return this.selectedCity.value;
  }

  cityChanged(city : City) {
      this.selectedCity = city;
  }
}
```

Comment: purpose of using `getSelectedValue()` method? where is it being used?

Comment: `getSelectedValue()` is a simple accessor method for the numeric value of the currently selected value.  It's simply to demonstrate that difference, you can safely remove it if it doesn't fit your implementation.

Comment: I have implemented your approach, but it did not work. It is still showing the first index item which is `None`

Comment: Here is a working implementation of my suggestion on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-b9dent).  If yours isn't working you need to provide some additional information before I can help you further.

Comment: With your changes, he has to change `$event.value` by `$event` in html

Comment: In the provided code they are passing `$event.value` to the `cityChanged` method, which takes a `City` object and then assigns the `city.value` to `this.selectedCity`.  I don't think they need the whole event when they already have the `City`.  Passing the whole `$event` simply gives them the `MouseEvent` in addition to the value